# htaccess redirect 301 does not work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

There was an old site, and all your URLs have changed.

One URL that was well found on Google was:

mydomain.com/datacenters

Now I want to redirect this URL to:

mydomain.com/data-centers

In htaccess I did:

```
redirect 301 /datacenters /data-centers
```

But it does not work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't  work"? Are you getting any server side error ?

Comment: Error 404... and don´t make the redirection @starkeen

Comment: Does the new uri `/data-center` exist on your server?

Comment: Yes, but the URL in the browser continues /datacenters

Comment: Yes, i got 500 error

Comment: Do you have more rules in your .htaccess? DId you try from a new browser?

Comment: I cleaned all htaccess to solve the problem.
Does the old file need to exist on the server?

Comment: This is the same?

RewriteRule ^datacenters http://mydomain.bla/data-centers [END,R=301]

Comment: Yes this `RewriteRule` will also work. `RewriteRule` is more powerful because of regex matching capabilities.

Comment: Thans, so i gone use RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0):

Only work with:

```
RewriteRule ^datacenters http://mydomain.bla/data-centers [L,R=301,NC]
```